# Pandas: pairwise multiplication of columns based on column name

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'ap1_X':[1,2,3,4], 'as1_X':[1,2,3,4], 'ap2_X':[2,2,2,2], 'as2_X':[3,3,3,3]})
>>> df
   ap1_X  as1_X  ap2_X  as2_X
0      1      1      2      3
1      2      2      2      3
2      3      3      2      3
3      4      4      2      3
```

I would like to multiply `ap1_X` with `as1_X` and put that value in `as1_X`, similarly for `ap2_X` with `as2_X`. The common identifier here is the number that comes after the `ap` or `as`.

The final DataFrame should look like this

```
>>> df
   ap1_X  as1_X  ap2_X  as2_X
0      1      1      2      6
1      2      4      2      6
2      3      9      2      6
3      4      16     2      6
```

I know I can loop through the columns and multiply the columns that have the same 3rd character in the column name, but I was wondering if there is a more "pandas" way of doing this?

UPDATE: The number ID in the column name can be multiple digits (ex: 1, 2, ..., 12, ..., 100).  So basically, the ID is the number between 'ap' or 'as', and '_X'.

Answer (score 3):

You can do `groupby` with `axis=1` and key is the common number

```
df.groupby(df.columns.str[2],axis=1).prod()
Out[73]: 
    1  2
0   1  6
1   4  6
2   9  6
3  16  6
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) here:

```
df.filter(like='p') * df.filter(like='s').values

   ap1_X  ap2_X
0      1      6
1      4      6
2      9      6
3     16      6
```

---

Another solution is to [`argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) the column names and slice. This should be very efficient.

```
idx = np.argsort(df.columns.str[1])
l = len(df) // 2
df.iloc[:, idx[:l]] * df.iloc[:, idx[l:]].values 

   ap1_X  ap2_X
0      1      6
1      4      6
2      9      6
3     16      6
```